# transform raw query to mongodb query the efficient way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongodb-query

In a nodejs app with mongodb storage, I have the following query from user:

```
const rawQuery = [
  '{"field":"ingredient","type":"AND","value":"green and blue"}',
  '{"field":"ingredient","type":"AND","value":"black"}',
  '{"field":"ingredient","type":"OR","value":"pink"}',
  '{"field":"ingredient","type":"OR","value":"orange"}',
  '{"field":"place","type":"AND","value":"london"}',
  '{"field":"school","type":"NOT","value":"fifth"}',
  '{"field":"food","type":"OR","value":"burger"}',
  '{"field":"food","type":"OR","value":"pizza"}',
  '{"field":"ownerFirstName","type":"AND","value":"Jimmy"}'
];
```

I have a collection called restaurant, and a collection called owners.

Would this query aim to handle such a search scenario?

```
  const query = {
        $and: : [
            { ingredient: 'green and blue' },
            { ingredient: 'black' },
            { $or : [
                    { ingredient: 'pink' },
                    { ingredient: 'orange' },
                ] 
            },
            { place: 'london' },,
            { school: { $ne: 'fifth' } },
            { $or : [
                    { food: 'burger' },
                    { food: 'pizza' },
                ] 
            }
        ]
  };
```

How can I transform the rawQuery into this mongo query? (Given that it has to be dynamic, because I have many fields, and in this example I just included a couple of them.)

This example query aims to get the restaurants that match the description/place/school/food queries in the restaurant and also to match the owner's first name from another collection. Each restaurant document will have a ownerUuid field that points to the owner in the other collection.

What is the best solution to do a search in the mongodb for such a query in production env?

How can this be achieved with Elasticsearch?

Comment: Could you include your schema? If the fields are arrays, you can query them with `$all` / `$in` instead of `$and` / `$or`

Comment: @TheeSritabtim the schema for each of the fields is String.... none of them are arrays or objects...

Comment: In that case, does it make sense to have `AND` operator on the same field? Or is it going to be partially matched? Like `ingredient` can not be both `'green and blue'` and `'black'`

Comment: it is a partial match... a full ingredient field could hold this: `green and blue and black and yellow` @TheeSritabtim

Comment: Your data are not stored correctly, so you cannot build such dynamic query. `ingredient: 'green and blue'` means your `ingredient` contains exactly `green and blue`, not `blue and green`. I recommend you save `ingredient` field as `Array` (any field which holds multiple values) and then we can see if it's possible to build such query